# What is <<-CMD in the Capistrano source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

In the capistrano 2.15.5 [deploy:assets source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb) I see code that looks like this:

```
desc <<-DESC
  [internal] This task will set up a symlink to the shared directory \
  ... more
DESC

run <<-CMD.compact
  rm -rf #{latest_release}/public/#{assets_prefix} &&
  ... more
CMD
```

What exactly is happening with this syntax? It looks like a way to write a string without quotes, akin to %q. Is `<<-` an operator? Or `<<-CMD` and `<<-DESC` weirdly named constants? Or this means nothing in normal Ruby but rather a feature of the Capistrano DSL?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax is called a heredoc or here document (because it's included 'right here') and is indeed a way to write long, multi-line strings without quotes. It's not specific to Capistrano, but part of Ruby (and many other languages too, going as far back as old UNIX shells.) The [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)  have all the details if you want to learn more.

Comment: Thanks. What's going on with the .compact?

Comment: That's String.compact from Capistrano. It collapses repeated spaces if I recall correctly.